# reCAPTCHA V2 not working with www.recaptcha.net

Tags: recaptcha

According to developer FAQ I've tried to use "www.recaptcha.net" in circumstances when "www.google.com" is not accessible and it is not working as expected as internally still using some reCAPTCHA APIs from "www.google.com" only. Is there anything we can do here?

Thanks,
Ankit

[Network calls for loading reCAPTCHA V2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYwjn.png)

Comment: Isn't this because reCAPTCHA V2 is deprecated? reCAPTCHA V3 is out

Comment: reCAPTCHA V1 is deprecated and reCAPTCHA V3 is in beta phase.

Comment: ahh ok my apologies! :v